# GoogleMap V2 Failed to load map.Error contacting Google servers

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using  a `Google Api 19.`I am getting the Stacktrace error at runtime while running the Google map V2. Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).

**StackTrace:**

```
 E/Random(2450)          : > 17.384058210414967, 78.48609545247936
 E/Random(2450)          : > 17.385480575802443, 78.48634970995319
 E/Random(2450)          : > 17.384707320313552, 78.48718165182942
 E/Random(2450)          : > 17.384469518257607, 78.48737972822704
 E/Random(2450)          : > 17.386012910991372, 78.48664538492055
 E/Random(2450)          : > 17.384268963692328, 78.48682608163563
 E/Random(2450)          : > 17.385942881352822, 78.48616019819285
 E/Random(2450)          : > 17.384971626221553, 78.48736770924768
 E/Random(2450)          : > 17.384794739104553, 78.48631955135781
 E/Random(2450)          : > 17.38564903886939, 78.48614895429334
 D/gralloc_goldfish(2450): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
 I/Choreographer(2450)   : Skipped 621 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 E/Google Maps Android API(2450): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
     android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Goolge API Key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyB2p7rsFLCuYmjA8SnRsIZfjWugwgh4wtU" />

    </application>   

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.map.googlemap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

            // Changing map type
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);


            // Showing / hiding your current location
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable zooming controls
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);

            // Enable / Disable my location button
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable Compass icon
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable Rotate gesture
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable zooming functionality
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

            double latitude = 12.987100;
            double longitude = 80.251692;

            // lets place some 10 random markers
            for (int i = 0; i <1; i++) {
                // random latitude and logitude
                double[] randomLocation = createRandLocation(latitude,
                        longitude);

                // Adding a marker
                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                        new LatLng(randomLocation[0], randomLocation[1]))
                        .title("Hello Maps " + i);

                Log.e("Random", "> " + randomLocation[0] + ", "
                        + randomLocation[1]);

                // changing marker color
                if (i == 0)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));
                if (i == 1)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));

                googleMap.addMarker(marker);

                // Move the camera to last position with a zoom level
                if (i == 0) {
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(new LatLng(randomLocation[0],
                                    randomLocation[1])).zoom(15).build();

                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                            .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

    /**
     * function to load map If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }


    private double[] createRandLocation(double latitude, double longitude) {

        return new double[] { latitude + ((Math.random() - 0.5) / 500),
                longitude + ((Math.random() - 0.5) / 500),
                150 + ((Math.random() - 0.5) * 10) };
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

I doesn't know how to solve these stackTrace Error.Anybody can help me with these.Thank You.

Comment: Cross check your `API KEY`

Comment: @SimplePlan I think there was nothing problem with api key.with the help of google console and then SHA1 fingerprint I get an api key.

Comment: @SimplePlan finally I am getting a blank screen.I am updated my edited post.

Comment: I faced the same issue in past and solved this by just generated new api key from google console and configure latest google play services. and also cross the Package name carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved these problem by doing the following steps:

- **In Emulator:**

  You have to use the latest API `Google APIs(Google Inc.)-API Level
  19`.

  Do the rest of the things placed in the screenshot itself.

  [image]
- **API Key:**

  Create New API Key and Check carefully about Google Map API key and SHA Key.
- **Google Play Services:**

  You have to download the latest Google Play Services
     [com.android.vending-4.8.20.apk](http://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23501681358540606).In that site if google play
     services wasn't working means you can find a lot of sites in
     internet named `com.android.vending 4.8.20.apk`.

  you can run the Google play Services by using the Command Prompt
     `adb install com.android.vending 4.8.20.apk`.

  **Note:** You have to download the latest Google play services because year by year latest version will be updated in internet.
- **output**:

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was in that I have used network_security_config setting in Manifest under the application tag.

I am still not sure how to handle it correctly but after I just removed that setting (occasionally it wasn`t needed for my project) Maps become to work.